# Mistake in a question in Fulton's algebraic curves book?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm trying to solve this question in Fulton's book *Algebraic Curves*:

[image]

I don't think this is true.

Counter-example: $k=\mathbb R$, $n=1$ and $F=X_1^2+1$.

Thanks

Comment: In your proposed counter-example, what is $a_1$?

Comment: @KeenanKidwell this is the problem, I can't factor $F$ in this way.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell for example, let's take $G= X_1^2-2X_1+1=(X_1-1)^2$ so the $a_1=1$ and $i_1=1$

Comment: Dear @user42912, Look at the statement to be proved. It involves the data of some $a_i$. In your case there would just be $a_1$. Your counter-example should be a polynomial $F\in\mathbf{R}[X-1]$ that can not be written as $\sum_i \lambda_i (X_1-a_1)^i$ for any $\lambda_i$. What is $a_1$ in your counter-example?

Comment: Dear @user42912, That's an example, not a counter-example. You might be interested in searching for "several variable Taylor expansion" or something along those lines.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell yes, it's just to show you that I can factor $G$ in this way, but I can't do the same with $F$.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell Following the question $F\in \mathbb R[X_1]$, no?

Comment: Yes, you can. It's the Taylor expansion around $1$! Take $F(X_1)=X_1^2+1$. We have $F(1)=2$, $F^\prime(1)=2$, and $F^{\prime\prime}(1)=2$. Can you verify that $F=2+2(X_1-1)+(X_1-1)^2$? In my post above, $\mathbf{R}[X-1]$ was supposed to be $\mathbf{R}[X_1]$.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell yes, thank you very much, I think I misread the question and I confused sum with multiplication which is not true since $k$ is not necessarily an algebraically closed field.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell please can you add this example in your answer so that I can upvote it and maybe check the answer tomorrow?

Comment: Fulton is, needless to say, absolutely right (see comments above  and answers below). You must realize that $i$ is an $n$-tuple, namely $i=(i_1,..., i_n)\in \mathbb N^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true. Keep in mind the $i_j$ can be zero. Consider the $k$-algebra endomorphism $k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]\to k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ given by $X_i\mapsto X_i-a_i$. Can you prove this is surjective? That would give you what you want...

If you just want to think about one variable, this is the Taylor expansion around $a=a_1$ (there is a several variable version involving partial derivatives as well, but I think that's not the easiest way to prove the statement in general). For the example of $F(X)=X^2+1\in k[X]$ ($k$ any field) and $a=1$, what is the Taylor expansion? It's $F(X)=F(1)+F^\prime(1)+F^{\prime\prime}(1)/2!+\cdots$, but the $\cdots$ is actually zero by all derivatives of $F$ of order $\geq 3$ are zero. So we just compute: $F(1)=2$, $F^\prime(1)=2$, and $F^{\prime\prime}(1)=2$. Plugging these values in to the formula gives

$$X^2+1=F(X)=2+2(X-1)+(2/2)(X-1)^2=2+2(X-1)+(X-1)^2.$$

Answer (score 3):

The notation is somewhat telegraphic, but I presume that
$$
\sum \lambda_{(i)}Y_1^{i_1}\dots Y_n^{i_n}\,,\qquad\lambda_{(i)}\in k
$$
is just how you would represent an arbitrary polynomial in $k[Y_1,\dots,Y_n]$.
 Then, given $a_1,\dots,a_n$, elements of $k$, you just set $Y_i=X_i-a_i$, so clearly $k[X]=k[Y]$.

Comment: why $k[X]=k[Y]$? it's not so obvious for me.

Comment: Just by substitution. Can’t you express every polynomial in the $X$s as, instead, a polynomial in the $Y$s? And vice versa?